# PHP Adding array to multidimensional array at key inside foreach

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, foreach

I'm trying to add an array to another array at key inside a foreach loop.  Here is my function.  Here is my function:

```
    $dirs = scandir( $dir );
    $results = array( 'folders' => [] );

    foreach ( $dirs as $dir ) {

            if ( is_dir( $this::uploads_path() . '/' . $dir ) ) {
                array_push( $results['folders'], $dir );    
            } else {

                $file = array(
                    'filename' => $dir,
                    'filesize' => 1000
                );

                $results['files'][] = $file;

            }

    }

    return $results;
```

It seems however I try, I get keys with empty values. Like this:

```
 'files' => 
    array (size=7)
      0 => 
        array (size=2)
          ...
      1 => 
        array (size=2)
          ...
      2 => 
        array (size=2)
          ...
      3 => 
        array (size=2)
          ...
      4 => 
        array (size=2)
          ...
      5 => 
        array (size=2)
          ...
      6 => 
        array (size=2)
          ...
```

I've also tried delaying adding the array by building a new array with the file information and adding it to $results outside the foreach loop.  Thanks for the help.  Would love an explanation as to why I'm getting empty values rather than just a fixed code example.

Comment: Please show input example and expected output.

Comment: What are you using to print array?  I'm not aware of anything that'll give you "size=7" and "size=2", for example.  Not var_export, print_r, nor var_dump.  Whatever it is, "size =2" implies the sub-arrays are in fact there with 2 elements such as with keys `filename` and `filesize` ... but instead it prints `...` for brevity.

Comment: I was wondering about that.  I'm using var_dump with Xdebug extension.

Comment: Try `var_dump($results['files'][0])` to confirm what's really there.

Comment: Wow....  Looks like its some kind of abbreviation.  It's all there. I just started using Xdebug, is that a normal facet of Xdebug (that array was also nested in another array with some code).  Sorry for the dumb question everyone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Xdebug documentation for var_dump](https://xdebug.org/docs/display)

> Xdebug replaces PHP's var_dump() function for displaying variables. Xdebug's version includes ... and places limits on the amount of array elements/object properties, maximum depth and string lengths.

As you said above, your are using var_dump and xdebug.  It is limiting the depth of arrays its printing.  So instead of seeing your real data, xdebug is truncating it to `...` (after indicating `size=2`).

Looks like you can set `xdebug.var_display_max_depth` to increase the depth.

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

just remove the } before return.

After I remove, I've test it.

kris-roofe@krisroofe-Rev-station:~$ php test.php
array(2) {
  ["folders"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(1) "."
    [1]=>
    string(2) ".."
  }
  ["files"]=>
  array(25) {
    [0]=>
    array(2) {
      ["filename"]=>
      string(9) ".ICE-unix"
      ["filesize"]=>
      int(100)
    }
    [1]=>
    array(2) {
      ["filename"]=>
      string(10) ".Test-unix"

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  That was a mistake left in from an irrelevant if statement.  I removed it from the question for clarity.

Comment: Thanks but that was not the issue